# SQL-Server query en PHP no devuelve resultados

Tags: php, sql-server

Tengo una consulta sobre una BBDD SQL-Server que ejecuto con Management Studio y me devuelve como resultado 4 filas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego usando los ejemplos en PHP sobre como obtener dicho resultado y trabajar con él:

```
$resultado=array();
$serverNameNEW = "192.168.1.XXX";
$connectionOptionsNEW = array(
        "Database" => "XXX",
        "Uid" => "XX",
        "PWD" => "XXX"
    );
$connNEW = sqlsrv_connect($serverNameNEW, $connectionOptionsNEW);

$sqlNEW= 
"
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
( 
    SELECT 
        distinct(Lote) AS 'ID', 
        operario_id as 'OPERARIO', 
        LEFT(maquina_id, 5) AS 'PUESTO', 
        CodMaterial AS 'ARTICULO', 
        DescMaterial AS 'DESCRIPCION', 
        Orden AS 'ORDEN', '' as 'FECHA', 
        DescMotivoMalas as 'MOTIVO', 
        zona_nme AS 'LUGAR' 
    FROM T1
    LEFT JOIN T2 on T1.Lote = T2.id 
    LEFT JOIN T3 ON T2.idMotivoMalas = T3.IdMotivoMalas 
    LEFT JOIN T4 ON T2.idZona = T4.zona_id 
    LEFT JOIN T5 on T1.IdMatOF=T5.idmatof 
    LEFT JOIN T6 on T6.IdBoletin=T5.IdBoletin 
    WHERE convert(varchar, CONVERT(date, dhEntrada, 106),103) >= CAST('01/06/2015' AS DATE) 
    AND convert(varchar, CONVERT(date, dhEntrada, 106),103) <= CAST('10/06/2015' AS DATE) 
    AND T1.operario_id IS NOT NULL 
    AND Estado='4' 
AND LEFT(T0.maquina_id,5) = '06001' 
UNION 
SELECT 
    CID COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS 'ID', 
    COPERARIO COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS 'OPERARIO', 
    CPUESTO COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS 'PUESTO', 
    CARTICULO COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS 'ARTICULO', 
    DESCRIPCION COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS 'DESCRIPCION', 
    CORDEN COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS 'ORDEN', 
    '' AS 'FECHA', 
    ISNULL(CNOMBRE COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, '') AS 'MOTIVO', 
    ISNULL(CNOMBRE COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS, '') AS 'LUGAR' 
FROM T0 
LEFT JOIN T1 ON T1.NMARCAJE = T0.NCODIGO COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
LEFT JOIN T2 ON T2.CCODIGO = T1.CINCIDENCIA COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
LEFT JOIN T3 ON T2.CUBICACION = T3.CCODIGO COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
LEFT JOIN T4 ON T4.ARTICULO = T0.CARTICULO COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
WHERE FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT('20', SUBSTRING(T0.DFECHA, 7, 2), '/', SUBSTRING(T0.DFECHA, 4, 2), '/', SUBSTRING(T0.DFECHA, 1, 2), SUBSTRING(T0.DFECHA, 9, 9)), 120), 'dd/MM/yyyy') >= CAST('01/06/2015' AS DATE) 
AND FORMAT(CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT('20', SUBSTRING(T0.DFECHA, 7, 2), '/', SUBSTRING(T0.DFECHA, 4, 2), '/', SUBSTRING(T0.DFECHA, 1, 2), SUBSTRING(T0.DFECHA, 9, 9)), 120), 'dd/MM/yyyy') <= CAST('10/06/2015' AS DATE) 
AND T0.CID <> '0000000000' 
AND T0.CID <> '9999999999' 
AND T0.CID <> 'NULL' 
AND T0.CID IS NOT NULL 
AND T0.CPUESTO = '06001' 
AND T2.LRECUPERABLE = '2' 
GROUP BY T0.CID, T0.COPERARIO, T0.CPUESTO, T0.CARTICULO, T4.DESCRIPCION, T0.CORDEN, T0.DFECHA, T0.CNOMBRE, T0.CNOMBRE 
) AS T_TOTAL 
ORDER BY T_TOTAL.FECHA;
";
```

He añadido el código de la query, este mismo ejecutado en SQL Management Studio funciona y me devuelve resultaodos pero aqui no, lo unico diferente es que uso UNION para dos subconsultas pero no creo que sea el motivo ya que lo he usado otras veces y no ha dado problema alguno.

```
$stmtNEW = sqlsrv_query( $connNEW, $sqlNEW);

while( $resultado[$i] = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtNEW ))
{
    echo "HAY UNA LINEA";
}
```

Y no obtengo ningún resultado no entiendo el porque.

Comment: Que es `$resultado[$i]`?

Comment: Respuesta editada, es un array

Comment: Probaste cambiando las fechas a YYYYMMDD?

Comment: Si, y sigue sin mostrar resultados

Answer (score 0):

Si la conexión a la `BBDD` es correcta y la `SQL` esta bien hecha, el bucle `while` lo haría de esta manera:

```
while( $resultado = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtNEW ))
{
   echo $resultado['ID']. " " .$resultado['ARTICULO']. "<br>";
}
```

**Código completo:**

```
$resultado=array();
$serverNameNEW = "192.168.1.XXX";
$connectionOptionsNEW = array(
        "Database" => "XXX",
        "Uid" => "XX",
        "PWD" => "XXX"
    );
$connNEW = sqlsrv_connect($serverNameNEW, $connectionOptionsNEW);
$sqlNEW= "MISMA CONSULTA QUE EN MANAGEMENT STUDIO";
$stmtNEW = sqlsrv_query( $connNEW, $sqlNEW);

while( $resultado = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmtNEW ))
{
   echo $resultado['ID']. " " .$resultado['ARTICULO']. "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Acabo de probar tu solución, ningún resultado devuelto

Comment: Prueba a poner debajo de `$connNEW` `if( $connNEW) {
     echo "Conexión establecida.<br />";
}else{
     echo "Conexión no se pudo establecer.<br />";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}`

Comment: Conexión establecida devuelve!

Comment: Vale, poco a poco, ahora pon debajo de `$stmtNew` `if( $stmtNew === false ) {
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}`

Comment: No devuelve nada, es decir, $stmtNEW es true

Comment: Aquí viene un ejemplo claro: [ManualPHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array.php)

Comment: Yo quitaría la variable `$resultado = array();` No haria falta declararla como array

Comment: Lo he quitado, es cierto no hacia falta, pero sigue sin mostrar resultados

Comment: Pues no veo nada raro la verdad, te conecta bien a la BBDD y la SQL esta bien, entonces no entiendo porque no muestra resultados..

Comment: He depurado y me sale lo siguiente: Warning: sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in prueba.php

Comment: Eso creo que es porque la SQL no la está haciendo bien. Si puedes poner la query que estás haciendo o un ejemplo parecido podremos ver qué falla

Comment: He modificado mi pregunta para que ves la query

Answer (score 0):

```
function sqlConsulta($conexion)
{

    $sqlNumArt="TU_CONSULTA_SQL";

    $resultadoNumArt=$conexion->prepare($sqlNumArt);
    $resultadoNumArt->execute();

    while($rowNumArt = $resultadoNumArt->fetch())
    {
        $numArt = $rowNumArt['ID'];
        $Art = $rowNumArt['Articulo'];
    }

    return($...);
```

Te muestro un ejemplo de una consulta `SQL` a modo de función por si te sirve de ayuda.

Comment: Prueba el siguiente código para asegurar que devuelve un resultado: <br> `$results = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query); //ejecuta la query
$row_count = sqlsrv_num_rows( $results );
if($row_count>0){
  $hay = true;
}else{
  die("No hay resultados a mostrar");
}`